# Can you introduce a Jon Skeet badge?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badge-request, specific-user

I was answering a question on Stack Overflow and saw that Jon Skeet was also active and commenting on the original question. I eventually answered the question correctly.

So can I have a badge saying I beat Jon Skeet? :)

Comment: Jon's cool and all but can't we give it a little rest already?

Comment: We should introduce the badge a Jon Skeet.

Comment: Add a "Jon Skeet" badge for anyone over 1,000,000 rep points..

Comment: Of course it would be a Platinum badge..

Answer (score 39):

We don't focus on users here, but on content. As much as I like Mr. Skeet (a lot), I don't think it would be a good idea to introduce a badge like this.

Badges in general are supposed to promote and reward positive behavior. Trying to "beat" Jon Skeet on answers for the sake of it isn't. This could also have the unfortunate side effect that people will start posting low quality answers to every question Jon Skeet answers, essentially cluttering these questions with gob.

I am against this proposal.

Answer (score 16):

There would be a way to implement a badge like this without focusing on one specific person - like, for example, defining a badge you get when posting a higher-ranked answer than any one of Stack Overflow's top 10 or top 20 users.

Even that would be a bad idea, though. While the site's current top 10 (and surely also the top 20) are incredibly knowledgeable people, no one has ever said that they know everything best - nor should we have badges that support this superstition.

"Beating" a top 10 user's answer may give you a personal sense of satisfaction, and that's great. It shouldn't ever be an official thing, though.